# Passing parameter to exe

Tags: c#

I have made exe of c# console application. I want to pass app.config file as parameter to run that exe. When I pass config file with same name as that of exe, it works fine. But if I change name or path of that config file, it starts giving error that

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can you please help me resolving this ? Also let me know if we can pass multiple config files at a time to same exe.

Thanks,
Mandar

Comment: any code snippets?

Comment: By **passing** you mean make the exe **use** a config file that you specific?

Comment: I am running exe like {exename}.exe "{exename}.exe.config" ...But I want any config should work fine. e.g {exename}.exe "demo.config" !!

Comment: @Mandar you can have [multiple config files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration) for a single project.  if you have app.config, then {exename}.exe.config will be generated.  check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674759/do-i-need-app-config)

Answer (score 1):

By default ConfigurationManager class work with current application's default configuration. You can change the file name however you have to use appropriate method e.g. OpenExeConfiguration.

There are many ways you can achieve this in C# console application.

One is explained here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

Yes you can accept n number of arguments from command line and you can use them as file name to be read.

Remember configuration file is just like any other file (in XML format), as long as you have a valid file name and path you can read its content one or the other way.

If this does not help post your code; how you are loading and reading the configuration file.